# How to call constructor from another class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I am newbie to JavaScript, and I would like to instantiate an object from another class.

**person.js:**

```
function Person(first,last){
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
}

Person.prototype = {}
```

**Hello.js:**

```
var per = require('person');

var persons = [];
persons.push(new Person('mike','smith'));
```

Person is undefined in Hello.js.

Thanks

Comment: `var Person = require('person')` (otherwise it'd be `new per`) and assuming this is node don't forget to add `module.exports = Person` at the end of the file.

Comment: You're very welcome - consider reading the Node tutorial on modules - it should clarify this further and help with any further doubts you might have.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the script `person.js` before your `Hello.js`, so that the `Person` class shall be defined.

Something like

```
<script src="./person.js"></script>
<script src="./Hello.js"></script>
```

Unless you're not in the browser (in node or other environment), or using some dependency manager like browserify (like you implied writing `var per = require('person');` )

In that case, in your `person.js` file, add `module.exports = Person;` at the end so that it could be required and then in your `Hello.js`, use the variable you required to instanciate your class : `new per('mike','smith');`